# Combinatoria con Suma de Columnas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Tengo cuatro variables X1,X2,X3 y X4, las cuales tienen la condición de que en su suma deben de darme siempre 1. Es decir cada variable representa un porcentaje de un total del 100 %. Pero este porcentaje se basa en un **"paso"**, si defino mi paso como por ejemplo `paso = 0.25`, tengo menos combinaciones posibles (menos filas), eso si defino un paso más pequeño como `paso = 0.01` eso me dará como resultado más filas.

Imagen para entender la idea:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso el paso definido es **paso = 0.25** por lo cual como podemos observar hay 35 combinaciones posibles, por ende 35 filas que me pueden sumar 1, sin que su valor se repita.

Lo que quiero hacer es replicar este ejercicio de excel en python, para lo cual empece haciendo lo siguiente:

```
def combinationSum(arr, sum):
    ans = []
    temp = []
 
    # first do hashing nothing but set{}
    # since set does not always sort
    # removing the duplicates using Set and
    # Sorting the List
    arr = sorted(list(set(arr)))
    findNumbers(ans, arr, temp, sum, 0)
    return ans
 
def findNumbers(ans, arr, temp, sum, index):
     
    if(sum == 0):
         
        # Adding deep copy of list to ans
        ans.append(list(temp))
        return
       
    # Iterate from index to len(arr) - 1
    for i in range(index, len(arr)):
 
        # checking that sum does not become negative
        if(sum - arr[i]) >= 0:
 
            # adding element which can contribute to
            # sum
            temp.append(arr[i])
            findNumbers(ans, arr, temp, sum-arr[i], i)
 
            # removing element from list (backtracking)
            temp.remove(arr[i])
 
 
# Driver Code
arr = [2, 4, 6, 8]
sum = 8
ans = combinationSum(arr, sum)
 
# If result is empty, then
if len(ans) <= 0:
    print("empty")
     
# print all combinations stored in ans
for i in range(len(ans)):
 
    print("(", end=' ')
    for j in range(len(ans[i])):
        print(str(ans[i][j])+" ", end=' ')
    print(")", end=' ')
```

En este código si como entrada le damos:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

La salida es:

```
( 2 2 2 2 ) ( 2 2 4 ) ( 2 6 ) ( 4 4 ) ( 8 )
```

Esto me sirvió como ayuda para empezar, pero ya estoy atorado de como continuar, pues toda mi salida debe tener cuatro valores, por ejemplo, en la salida (2 2 4) debe ser como (2 2 4 0), además que necesito implementar la condición del **paso** con todas las combinaciones posibles basadas en él y todo esto en un dataframe de Pandas.

¿Alguna idea de cómo podría implementar esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece un poco enredado la forma en que lo estás intentando hacer.

Este planteamiento es similar pero itera de atrás hacia adelante.

```
def iterate_step(step, length, total = 1):
    return _iterate_step(step, length, total)

def _iterate_step(step, length, total = 1, concat = [], should_sum = None, prev_data = []):
    if not should_sum:
        should_sum = total
    arr = [0] * length
    last = length - 1
    arr[last] = total
    while arr[last] > 0:
        if sum(arr + concat) == should_sum:
            prev_data.append(arr + concat)
        arr[last] = round(arr[last] - step, 2)
        if  length > 1:
            new_total = round(total - arr[last], 2)
            _iterate_step(step, last, new_total, arr[last:] + concat, should_sum, prev_data)
    return prev_data
    
combinations = iterate_step(2, 4, 8)
combinations2 = iterate_step(0.25, 4)
```

Vamos por partes.

Toda la funcionalidad de esta lógica, radica en `_iterate_step`. Este hace uso de la recursividad para iterar. Esta función acepta 5 parámetros, sin embargo 3 de ellos son única y exclusivamente para la recursividad por lo que no tiene mucho caso dejarlos abierta para su uso, es por ello que se ha tratado de dejar como privada (poniendo el guion bajo). Por ello fue que se creo una función aparte llamada `iterate_step`, la cuál sería la **pública** y solo acepta los parámetros que se pueden modificar, así se evitan errores.

```
def iterate_step(step, length, total = 1):
    return _iterate_step(step, length, total)
```

Esta función acepta 3 parámetros.

- **step:** Que es cada cuanto se debe modificar (lo que tú llamas paso, que en el ejemplo de la imagen es **0.25**)
- **length:** La cantidad de columnas que deseas (en tu caso el número de las columnas x que son 4)
- **total:** El total a sumar (en tu ejemplo de la imagen es 1.

Estos parámetros se pasan a la función privada. Esta función tiene otros 3 parámetros que solo sirven para la iteración

- **concat:** arreglo auxiliar que sirve para tener los número anteriores (se explica más adelante)
- **should_sum**: Este es el número inicial de `total` al inicio de la iteración, ya que durante la iteración, total va cambiando y debemos guardarlo para saber si cumple con la función
- **prev_data:** Aquí se va guardando todos los arreglo que son válidos para regresarlos al final.

Empecemos con la función

```
if not should_sum:
    should_sum = total
```

Esto, como se explico en la descripción de`should_sum` solo sirve para guardar el total del inicio, por lo que solo se usa en la primer iteración y se guarda el Carlo del total.

```
arr = [0] * length
```

Se crea un arreglo de 0 de la cantidad que se paso en length, por ejemplo en **4** se crearía lo siguiente `[0,0,0,0]`

```
last = length - 1
arr[last] = total
```

Se guarda el inidice del último elemento y el último elemento se transforma en el total en el caso de `total = 1` quedaría `[0,0,0,1]`

```
while arr[last] > 0:
```

Aquí se iterará hasta que el último elemento sea mayor a 0.

```
if sum(arr + concat) == should_sum:
    prev_data.append(arr + concat)
```

si la suma de todos los elementos de un array temporal de `concat` + `arr` es igual a `total` entonces lo Añadimos.
Como es la primera iteración, vemos en la definición que `concat = []` y vimos antes que `arr = [0,0,0,1]`, por lo que la suma de ambos arreglos es `[0,0,0,1]` y la suma de los elementos en este caso es `0 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 1`. `total = 1` por lo que `1 = 1` entonces añadimos `[0,0,0,1]`.

```
arr[last] = round(arr[last] - step, 2)
```

Una vez hecho esto, le restamos al último elemento el `step`. En el primer caso `1 - 0.75` Quedando el array como `arr = [0, 0, 0, 0.75]`

Si el arreglo tiene más de 1 elemento entonces es cuando entramos a la recursividad. Para ello debemos obtener el nuevo total, es decir, cuanto le falta al arreglo para que la suma de sus elementos sea igual al total. como nuestro total sigue siendo `1` y nuestro arreglo es `[0,0,0,0.75]` podemos ver que le falta `0.25` por lo que ese será nuestro nuevo total.

```
 _iterate_step(step, last, new_total, arr[last:] + concat, should_sum, prev_data)
```

Iteramos en la función
**step:** el mismo `step = 0.25`
**length:** Un un nuevo `length` que sería `length - 1`. Ese valor lo tenemos almacenado como `last`
**total:** ahora un nuevo total `new_total=0.25`,
**concat:** en este momento le pasamos el arreglo que cortamos, en este caso `[0.75]` + la parte que ya habíamos cortado que es el `concat`, en este caso vacío, pues no habíamos cortado antes.
**should_sum:** Le pasamos el total original.
**prev_data:** Le pasamos el arreglo original donde estamos guardando la info para que la siga guardando en el mismo arreglo.

Ahora iteramos de nuevo teniendo  `step = 0.25, length = 3, total = 0.25, concat = [0.75], should_sum = 1, prev_data = [[0,0,0,1]]`

```
if not should_sum:
   should_sum = total
```

Ya no aplica pues sí existe `should sum`

```
arr = [0] * length
last = length - 1
arr[last] = total
```

Ahora solo crea un arreglo de 3 elementos `[0,0,0.25]`

```
if sum(arr + concat) == should_sum:
   prev_data.append(arr + concat)
```

Vuelve a iterar pero esta vez `arr = [0,0,0.25]` y `concat = [0.75]`, por lo que el nuevo arreglo es `[0,0,0.25,0.75]` Como la suma de esto vale 1. Entonces se agrega al arreglo.

Si se sigue esa secuencia se puede entender la recursividad que usa.

En cuando a pandas simplemente puedes transformarlo a un dataframe de la siguiente forma.

`df = pd.DataFrame(combinations)`

Comment: personalmente quiero darle las gracias por, lejos del código que claro que funciona, la explicación tan clara que diste para la resolución del problema. Únicamente agregue un df = df.drop_duplicates() pues para un paso de 0.25 me daba 70 filas, cuando deberían de ser solo 35 posibilidades sin repetirse, y con eso ya quedo. Pero de nuevo GRACIAS, no sabes cuantas horas invertidas en este problema estuve dedicando.